# dir-locals not working

Tags: directory-local-variables, markdown, markdown-mode

I wanted to have wc-mode (a minor mode) enabled when I edit any markdown file in a specific directory. So, I created a `.dir-locals.el` file and added the following to it:

```
((markdown . ((wc-mode . t))))
```

But when I open a markdown file, it still does not have wc-mode enabled.

What am I doing wrong? How do I set it right?

Comment: You probably want `((markdown . ((mode . wc))))`.

Comment: Or you may try `((markdown . ((eval . (wc-mode)))))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To elaborate on theldoria's comments:

If `wc-mode` is a major mode then either:

```
((markdown-mode . ((mode . wc))))
```

or:

```
((markdown-mode . ((eval . (wc-mode)))))
```

If `wc-mode` is a minor mode, then:

```
((markdown-mode . ((eval . (wc-mode 1)))))
```

I have assumed that `markdown` was an error, and have substituted `markdown-mode`.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks. I realized that I could have mentioned that wc-mode is a minor mode. I have edited the question to reflect this.

Comment: For `eval` to work update of `safe-local-eval-forms` might be required.